# Google apps script: Get folder name from file

Tags: google-apps-script

in google apps script I have this code:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
 'modifiedDate > "2013-02-28" and title contains "untitled"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

How can I get the name of the folder where the file resides type this code:

```
var folderName = folder.getName(); // ?
```

thank you for help

raffaele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.getParents()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents()) of File class to get a collection of folders ([FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)) that are immediate parents of the file:

```
var fileParents = file.getParents();
while ( fileParents.hasNext() ) {
  var folder = fileParents.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
}
```