# Email Google Slides As PDF Using Template and Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to make a menu item that someone can open a slide, click a button, and it will save the Slide deck as a PDF and email it (using a pre-defined template).  I started by working on the scripting for saving the PDF, but I am getting errors. Request help!

```
    function onOpen() {
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('RightTrak Mailer')
      .addItem('Save PDF', 'SavePDF')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}

function SavePDF() {
  folderString = "1vozH-LotRA0xzZwWNxP-sVRirVvswSTl"
  var blob = 
   DriveApp.getFileById("1zd7BecVSJupY0GOebJCTEQKwR_SDLWOxCeoRfwCL2fQ").getBlob();
  var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vozH-LotRA0xzZwWNxP-sVRirVvswSTl");
  dir.DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  SlidesApp.getUi()
    .alert('Saved to ' + folderString + " " + blob.getName())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I Created a test Google Slides and Added your Script the First Error I came Across was:

> Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because
> you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access
> it.

Of course your HardCoded File ID Needed to be changed to mine.  I did this with getActivePresnetation().   But there is the possibility you were getting an error becasue you had the wrong id.  I also found code to get the Folder ID, but then was curious why you wanted to use the long Folder ID in your Saved Name String shown to the user on the alert.  I changed that to the folder Name. But your choice, you can change with the indexing on the item returned by the getFolderInfo function. Shown below is code that gets both the Slide Deck and Folder Ids programmatically instead of having to paste them in. That should fix any errors you might have had with wrong Ids.

Your Line "dir.DriveApp.createFile(blob);"  Has one problem, the 'dir' is a type Folder, that has its own method createFile.  It does not need the DriveApp  between dir and createFile. That line changes to: "dir.createFile(blob);"  That is referenced Here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder

I was able to get the following code to work on a Google Slide Deck and have it Save a Copy of the Slide Deck as a PDF.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('RightTrak Mailer')
      .addItem('Save PDF', 'SavePDF')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}

function getFolderInfo(inputFile)
{
  // found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674758/google-apps-script-get-folder-name-from-file
  var fileParents = inputFile.getParents();
  while ( fileParents.hasNext() ) 
  {
    var folder = fileParents.next();
    folderId = folder.getId();
    folderName = folder.getName();
  }
  return [folderId, folderName];
}

function SavePDF() {
  thisSlideDeck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  thisSdId = thisSlideDeck.getId();
  thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisSdId);
  thisFolderInfo = getFolderInfo(thisFile);
  var blob = thisFile.getBlob();
  var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById(thisFolderInfo[0]);
  dir.createFile(blob);
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Saved to ' + thisFolderInfo[1] + " " + blob.getName());
}
```